# How does spring kafka handle maintaining a heartbeat

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In the kafka consumer documentation https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html it states that care needs to taken to make sure poll is called every so often or the broker will assume the consumer is dead.

The most reliable procedure was pretty complicated:

> For use cases where message processing time varies unpredictably,
>   neither of these options may be sufficient. The recommended way to
>   handle these cases is to move message processing to another thread,
>   which allows the consumer to continue calling poll while the processor
>   is still working. Some care must be taken to ensure that committed
>   offsets do not get ahead of the actual position. Typically, you must
>   disable automatic commits and manually commit processed offsets for
>   records only after the thread has finished handling them (depending on
>   the delivery semantics you need). Note also that you will need to
>   pause the partition so that no new records are received from poll
>   until after thread has finished handling those previously returned.

Does spring kafka handle this for me under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

The heartbeat is mentioned very brief in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#stateful-retry). Apparently the heartbeat is managed by Spring-Kafka on a different thread.

> Since version 0.10.1.0 heartbeats are sent on a background thread

You can also read this [github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/248) to read more about the heartbeat.

Comment: spring-kafka 1.3.x and later use a much simpler threading model thanks to KIP-62; all users are recommended to upgrade to at least that version; the current version is 2.1.7.

Comment: I saw that github issue but it left me more confused it mentions how poll won't be called until the batch is completely processed https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/248#issuecomment-284775336 but the kafka documentation still says it's important to keep calling poll while processing is happening